# Android Studio does not open after initial screen appearance

Tags: android, android-studio

I had an old installation of Android studio. I tried to install flutter plugin, but that plugin was not listed there. I downloaded and installed latest version of Android Studio.
Now the issue is that when I try to open Android studio, its initial screen appears but then it just disappears. In Task Manager, Android Studio goes into Background process.

Comment: I think this question is slightly off-topic, but still would help if you say which Operating System you have, Java version, etc.

Comment: I have Windows-8 OS and Java jdk1.7.0_79